# Connecting to the XERO API

Tags: xero-api

We are new to the XERO API and looking on how to initially create a connection request and establish a connection

Any help greatly appreciated

thanks
john

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at our getting started guide: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/getting-started/getting-started-guide

The guide will walk you through setting up a dev account, creating an OAuth2 app in the dev portal, and enabling the demo company. It also links to our SDKs and Postman collection.

And our OAuth2 flow documentation:

Auth Code flow: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/auth-flow

PKCE flow: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/pkce-flow

Machine-Machine guide: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api-guides/machine-2-machine